# How to align C for-loop body w/ GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, for-loop, alignment, memory-alignment

In our embedded architecture we have a 64-bit IAB (Instruction Alignment Buffer). In order to optimize the fetch sequence, it is required that the body of a loop will start aligned to an 8-byte boundary.

It is easy to achieve this in assembly using the `.balign` directive, but I cannot find a syntax that will hint the C compiler to align the code.

Trying to precede the for loop with inline assembly with the `.balign` directive doesn't work as it aligns the for loop prolog (setup) and not the loop body itself.

Doing the same where the `asm()` line is inside the loop, adds `nop`-s to the loop body that cost precious cycles.

EDIT 1: assume the code:

```
    __asm__ volatile("nop");  
    __asm__ volatile("nop");  

    for (j0=0; j0<N; j0+=4)
    {
        c[j0+ 0] = a[j0+ 0] + b[j0+ 0];
        c[j0+ 1] = a[j0+ 1] + b[j0+ 1];
        c[j0+ 2] = a[j0+ 2] + b[j0+ 2];
        c[j0+ 3] = a[j0+ 3] + b[j0+ 3];
    }
```

I want the first `c=a+b` to be aligned to an 8-byte address. I can add the `nop`-s like above after a preliminary compilation, but this is an ad-hoc solution that will break with the 1st code change.

EDIT 2: Thanks to @R.., the solution is to use the `-falign-loops=8` compiler option.

Comment: So in essence, you want `nop`-s that will cause the the loop *body* to be aligned, but you want those `nop`-s to go before the loop *prolog*?

Comment: @ruakh - yes, although I don't care if the `nop`-s are generated in the prolog itself, as long as the branch instruction at the end of the loop points to an aligned memory location.

Comment: Umm, isn't this what GCC's `-falign-loops` option is for?

Comment: @R.. - This seems to be the trick! Please make it an answer so I can rep and accept it.

Comment: This, however, revealed a possible bug in our compiler, or in GCC in general: When more than a single `nop` is required, then zeros are being padded instead of additoinal `nop`-s. Same happens when `.balign` is used w/o fill value. Question is, how can I set a fill value for the command line switch?

Comment: If someone can confirm this is not a general GCC bug, it will be very helpful, thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the assembler rather than the compiler.

Comment: @R.. - I don't really know. I opened a new question for this one here - http://stackoverflow.com/q/9881002/274579

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Umm, isn't this what GCC's `-falign-loops` option is for?

Comment: Yes, but what if you want to affect a single loop only. Does GCC have any solution?

Comment: For a single function, you can use `#pragma GCC optimize` or the equivalent attributes. I don't know if you can do it on the single loop level though. If there's no other way, you might could achieve this with a horrible hack by putting the loop in a nested function and putting the attribute on the nested function...?

Comment: Targeted single-function optimization is still way better than project-wide option, since it can be good in some circumstances (hot loops) and bad in others (rare loops).

Unfortunately, neither `#pragma GCC optimize "align-loops=xx"` nor `__attribute__((optimize("align-loops=xx")))` seem to produce any effect in my tests (same `md5sum` on generated binaries).

Comment: relevant GCC request: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67435