# Is this a GCC bug when using -falign-loops option?

Tags: c, gcc, for-loop, alignment, memory-alignment

I was playing with this option to optimize a for-loop in our embedded architecture ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880510/how-to-align-c-for-loop-body-w-gcc)). However, I noticed that when the alignment requires more than a single `nop` instruction to be added, then the compiler generates one `nop` followed by as-many-as-required zeros (`0000`).

I suspect it is a bug in our compiler, but can someone confirm it is not a bug in GCC?

Here's a code snippet:

```
    __asm__ volatile("nop");  
    __asm__ volatile("nop");  

    for (j0=0; j0<N; j0+=4)
    {
        c[j0+ 0] = a[j0+ 0] + b[j0+ 0];
        c[j0+ 1] = a[j0+ 1] + b[j0+ 1];
        c[j0+ 2] = a[j0+ 2] + b[j0+ 2];
        c[j0+ 3] = a[j0+ 3] + b[j0+ 3];
    }
```

Compile with `-falign-loops=8` (or whatever number relevant to your architecture which is more than the required minimum alignment). You can add or remove the `__asm__` lines as necessary to generate misaligned loop body.

Comment: By the way, I would also get rid of the ugly manual loop unrolling and let gcc unroll the loops (which it will do by default with `-O3` when it thinks it makes sense).

Comment: @R.. - apparently, it is not so in the real world. This code is actually a part of a benchmark where I do vector addition. I have two functions, vecadd() with the above code and vecadd_naive() similar to your suggestion. The fact is that I had to manually unroll 16 times to get optimal performance, where more than marginally better than the naive version. This was with -O3 and (maybe redundant) -funroll-loops.

Comment: @R..- remember that the optimizer's heuristics for unrolling loops are based on a somewhat arbitrary set of rules (OK, at least arbitrary w.r.t the available options). Your considerations (like, code size or registers usage) may be different and lead to faster code after all. I guess this is what I see a difference.

Comment: You might be able to add a `#pragma` for optimization level/unrolling decision parameters before the loop instead of manually unrolling it. I'm undecided on whether this is nicer or uglier than unrolling the loop yourself though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `gcc -S -o foo.s foo.c` to generate the assembly output without assembling it. I suspect you'll see the `.balign` or `.p2align` directive in the asm. Assuming this directive is intended to work, I think it's a bug in the assembler. It's also possible that you've put the code in a non-default section (i.e. not `.text`) either intentionally or accidentally (e.g. with a misplaced `.data` or `.section` in some other inline asm); normally the assembler pads with the proper size and number of `nop` instructions for sections that contain code, and 0 bytes for sections that contain data.

Comment: Indeed, the compiler inserted the `.balign 8` directive to the correct place. Unfortunately, I already found out that when not given an explicit fill value, the assembler generates the erroneous sequence. As far as I can tell, the function is allocated in the `.text` section. I wonder if there is a way of telling the compiler to use a filler value when using `-falign-loops=n`, like when using `.balignw 8,0x01a2`?

Comment: Anyway, is this particular to our implementation, or is it a bug in GAS?

Comment: It's definitely possible if you edit the gcc source to change the string it inserts into the output assembly for alignment on your platform. Or you could make the change in GAS. Either change might be accepted upstream if the maintainers can confirm the problem exists.

Comment: Oh, well, I guess everything is possible when you have access to the source... I hoped there is an undocumented feature (as an extension for the option with similar syntax to the align directive).

Comment: Not as far as I know. Unless you're doing something strange with sections that's confusing the compiler/assembler, I'm pretty sure this is just a bug..

Comment: OK, here's a really cheap solution. Find the path your gcc is searching for binaries (it's probably under `/usr/lib/gcc` or similar) and put a shell script named `as` there. Have it run its input through `sed` to make the necessary fixes to alignment and run the real `as` binary.

Comment: Interesting idea. I will give it a try in one of the coming days.

Comment: OK. Remember the assembler could take input on a file or stdin. It's a bit harder to parse the command line to determine which argument is the filename to assemble (and avoid breaking other options at the same time), so if you can control the build environment, it would be easiest to just make sure gcc is always invoked with `-pipe` so the input to the assembler arrives on stdin. Then your wrapper script can just do `sed sed_expression_here | /real/path/to/as "$@"`

Comment: I do foresee a problem, though - how can we distinguish between an `.alignbw` intended for `nop`-s and `.alignbw` intended for zeros (for padding data objects, for example)...

Comment: If it's purely **padding** in data objects, why would it matter what the value is? The whole concept of padding is that it's not supposed to have any effect on the value. If this does turn out to be an issue, you can make a more advanced sed script with address ranges based on directives that change the section.

Comment: ... I donno... maybe b/c it is supposed to be so according to the GCC documentation?? Otherwise, I guess it really does not matter what the padding value is - except for the fact that it seemed important enough so the option for an explicit value was added to the align directive.

Comment: On most archs, the assembler inserts zero padding in data sections, and for code sections, it inserts optimum-size NOP instructions to achieve the desired padding with the fewest opcodes (this is possible only on archs where the opcode size is variable).